# Getting Multiple times same MQTT messages on single topic

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho, react-native-mqtt

I am developing an application with MQTT and here i am facing same messages are coming multiple times to the same topic instead of one message.

I am using a mosquitto broker, which is also bridged to another cloud private mosquitto broker and client is one paho mqtt client and An android MQTT Application.

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for above scenario. During publishing also we can experience multiple messages at the subscriber, just for one publish.

This is the Broker Configuration

```
connection GlowFY-GWY-b827eb83b211
address xx:xx:xx:xx:1883 
topic GlowFY/# both 0
```

Comment: Without seeing the code and probably how you have configured the bridge there is not enough information here to say anything.

Comment: connection GlowFY-GWY-b827eb83b211
address xx:xx:xx:xx:1883
topic GlowFY/# out 0
topic GlowFY/# in 0          This is the Bridge config. Is there any common mistake that could lead to these kind of mistakes. MQTT Settings is like QoS = 1, retain flags are false. Is there any specific setting that could lead to above issue

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74192747/edit) the question to add details

Comment: You probably have a bridge loop, try a single topic line with `both` not `in` or `out`

Comment: But that didnt help. Still recieving more messages in one publish . But if i remove the bridge between local and cloud broker, it functions normally. But with cloud the above scenario happens.

Comment: Please provide more details, e.g. which broker is the subscriber that is seeing multiple instances of the messages connected. Also show details of the publishing code as asked initially. Also define multiple, is it a fixed number of duplicates or a continuous stream of the same message?